# Winforms owner-drawn controls and resizing

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, gdi+, ownerdrawn

I am designing a control (below) called `ViewPanel`. Essentially it's just a panel that draws it's `Text` property as a title. To do this, I adjust the `DisplayRectangle` property to allow enough space at the top to draw some text.

The problem I am experiecing (and have been experiencing for a lot of owner-drawn controls that manipulate `DisplayRectangle`) is that when the control is resized, it's child controls seem to lag behind a bit.

**Example:**

[image: Example control]

As you can see here, I have a `ViewPanel` control, which has drawn a blue titlebar, also note that the `ViewPanel` is padded 16px in every direction!

The `ViewPanel` control has a single child (`ListView`)

I have resized the control - notice how the `ViewPanel` has drawn it's titlebar correctly, but the child has not repositioned itself accordingly.

**Question:**

What is responsible for updating the location of child controls? Do I need to override something?

Comment: Did you try setting the Anchor-property of the ListView to `Top,Left,Right,Bottom`?

Comment: I would recommend to set the Margin instead of using DisplayRectangle. Setting the margin will automatically adjust its child controls. . ..

Comment: @BastiM the ListView is set to dock.fill

Comment: @RohitPrakash I need to think broader than just this particular issue, I have a couple of controls that rely on changing the display rectangle

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved (for anyone else owner-drawing controls):

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    const int WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED = 0x0047;
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    if (m.Msg == WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED)
    {
        //Make changes to your display rectangle here...
        this.PerformLayout();
    }
}
```